# Selecting limited values in the rows of a column

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following issue. There is a column in my DataBase with postcode and place name.

```
5305EE Zuilichem         
1948NV Beverwijk          
1171CD Badhoevedorp       
7913TC Hollandscheveld    
4704SB Roosendaal
```

The issue is that I want to select in a column only a place name. I have tried 2 approaches so far and both are unsuccessful:

**1. Using iloc**

```
df["Place"] = df["Place"].loc[7:]
```

**2. Using regex**

```
df["Place"] = df["Place"].str.findall(r'A-Za-z')
```

However, both attempts have failed. Please let me know where is my mistake. Thank you in advance.

Comment: You might wanna try df["Place"].str.split(" ")?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`str.split`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html) setting `n=1` to limit the number of splits, and slice on the second element of the resulting lists:

```
df['Place'] = df.Place.str.split(n=1).str[1]
```

---

```
print(df)

    
   Place
0  Zuilichem         
1  Beverwijk          
2  Badhoevedorp       
3  Hollandscheveld    
4  Roosendaal
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```py
print(df.Place.str[7:])
```

Output

```
0          Zuilichem
1          Beverwijk
2       Badhoevedorp
3    Hollandscheveld
4         Roosendaal
```